# Как найти фигуру в матрице

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

Имеется матрица размером 2 на n, матрица подобного вида:

```
mat = [
    ['0','x','x','0','0','x']
    ['0','0','x','0','x','x']
]
```

x - занятая зона, 0 - пустая зона.
Нужно найти количество 'уголков' из нулей, но при этом эти 'уголки' могут быть повернуты на 90, 180 и 270 градусов. Сами уголки не могут пересекаться, например в матрице:

```
mat = [
    ['0','0','0','0']
    ['0','0','0','0']
]
```

будет 2 угла

Вот моя попытка написать код:

```
strings = (
'00x00x0xxx0',
'0xxx0x00x00'
)

ancount = 0
for i in range(len(strings[0])):
    try:
        if any([
            all([
                strings[0][i] == '0',
                strings[0][i + 1] == '0',
                (strings[1][i] == '0') and (strings[1][i + 1] == '0')
            ]),
            all([
                strings[1][i] == '0',
                strings[1][i + 1] == '0',
                (strings[0][i] == '0') and (strings[0][i + 1] == '0')
            ])
        ]):
            ancount += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass

print(f'Количество углов: {ancount}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strings = (
    '00x00x0xxx000',
    '0xxx0x00x0000'
)

mat = [list(x) for x in strings]

count = 0
i = 0

while i < len(mat[0]) - 1:
    # если найден уголок, сдвинемся еще раз, чтоб не искать пересекающиеся
    if sum((x[i:i + 2] for x in mat), []).count('0') >= 3:
        count += 1
        i += 1
    i += 1

print(count)  # 5
```

Comment: не важно что будет находится в оставшейся части угла, это можно увидеть в одном из примеров автора (`0000`,`0000`)

Comment: Если может быть ноль еще проще